# Extremely simple stack implementation using a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stack

Please review my simple `Stack`:

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack() = default;
    Stack(std::initializer_list<T> i) :n{} {
        for (auto& x : i) {
            elem.push_back(x);
            ++n;
        }
    }
    Stack(const Stack<T>&) = default;
    Stack(Stack<T>&&) = default;
    Stack& operator=(const Stack&) = default;
    Stack& operator=(Stack&&) = default;
    ~Stack() = default;
    int size() const {
        return n;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const {
        return (n == 0);
    }
    void push(T);
    T pop();
    T& peek();

private:
    std::vector<T> elem;
    int n;
};

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T t) {
    elem.push_back(t);
    ++n;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    T t = *elem.erase(elem.end()-1);
    --n;
    return t;
}

template<class T>
T& Stack<T>::peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    return elem[n-1];
}
```

How can I make this code better and build more complicated data structures based on stacks?

Comment: My first question is why do you need this at all?  Why not just use `std::stack`?

Comment: @John Dibling because I want to practice creating my own stack. I believe I can understand data structures more if I write one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `int n;`from member variable.
Underlying container `std::vector` holds the size information of the stack class. It **increases** the size of stack class object by `sizeof(int)`.

Remove various `default definition` methods from your class. Compiler would generate it for such classes. Due to these definition your class looks more verbose.

Implement all your member functions using the underlying container classes.

Prefer the standard name of your method instead of other. This way any program would easily use your custom class instead of `std::stack`. Change the `isEmpty()` to `empty()`

Your implementation can be simplified as below.

```
template<class T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack(const std::initializer_list<T>& i):elem(i) {}
    int size() const { return elem.size(); }
    bool empty() const { return elem.empty();}
    void push(const T&);
    T pop();
    T peek();
private:
    std::vector<T> elem;
};


template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(const T& t) {
    elem.push_back(t);
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    auto x = elem.back();  
    elem.pop_back();
    return x;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::peek() {
    if (empty()) {
        throw std::out_of_range("underflow");
    }
    return elem.back();
}
```

Comment: How about `Stack(const std::initializer_list<T> &i) : elem(i){}`?

Comment: @nwp: Yes you are right. I have added this suggestion.

Comment: Your `pop` looks bad to me, the order of last two statements is wrong (use `auto tmp = elems.back(); elems.pop_back(); return tmp;`)

Comment: Just now I realized that, author wants to return the value which is going to erased. Hence we need to save it before calling the pop_back.

Answer (score 3):

There's a reason `std::stack` doesn't provide a `pop()` that returns the popped element: exception safety. Returning the popped element by value from `pop()` may require calling the copy constructor (although the compiler may be able to elide the copy) which in general may throw. If it throws you will lose the popped element and therefore your stack's `pop()` doesn't meet the [Strong Exception Safety Guarantee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety).

This may not matter for your use case but I think it's worth understanding why the standard library version of a stack doesn't provide a pop that returns the popped element but has a separate `top()` and void-returning `pop()`.